# Render memory usage optimization

Tags: rendering

When rendering, blender is only using 20-40m of my memory but i have 4gb of ram, is there a way to allow it to use more memory for rendering?

Comment: Why would you want to use more memory? Developers go to great lengths to try and optimize the rendering process so it uses as little as possible memory

Answer (score 4):

Using more RAM for render doesn't give any speed up for render. Blender uses as much memory as it needs.

Comment: Nitpicking, actually it uses as **little** as it needs, so it can fit the most into memory to render more complex scenes